# Dynamically modifying attributes of an instance

Tags: python, oop, python-3.4

I have my problem solved, but I would like to know why.

My situation is as following:

I defined the class Vector as:

```
class Vector:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

And the following instance created:

```
v1 = Vector(1,1)
```

Why the following code doesn't work

```
def plus_one_A(thing):
    attrs = vars(thing)
    for attr_name, value in attrs.items():
        if type(value) == int or type(value) == float:                
            eval('thing.'+ attr_name + ' += 1')
    return thing

v2 = plus_one_A(v1)

thing.x += 1 
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But the following does?

```
def plus_one_B(thing):
    attrs = vars(thing)
    for attr_name, value in attrs.items():
        if type(value) == int or type(value) == float:                
            setattr(thing, attr_name, value + 1)
    return thing

v2 = plus_one_B(v1)
```

Isn't supposed those codes to be equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) instead of [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval). `eval` can be used only for a [**expression**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html), not `statement`.

```
>>> eval('1 + 2')
3
>>> eval('x = 1 + 2')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
    x = 1 + 2
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
>>> exec('x = 1 + 2')
>>> x
3
```

BTW, [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) not only accept a type object, but also accept a tuple of types for the second parameter.

```
>>> isinstance(1, (int, float))
True
>>> isinstance(1.0, (int, float))
True
>>> isinstance('1', (int, float))
False
```

Comment: Hey, great answer!. That was what I was missing, now I know the difference between `exec()` and `eval()` (I thought they were the same, but I should have supposed that in Python `There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it`). Great tip about `isinstance()` BTW